# GWT CellTable column resizing/sorting

Tags: gwt

Has anybody found a way to make the GWT CellTable allow user resizing of columns?  We are moving away from the old gwt-incubator widgets as they seem to have some compatibility issues with GWT 2.1+ and still need this functionality which it had previously.

Also, if we could have simple sorting like the incubator used to provide that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LOL
You asked that question 6 hours after [column resizing was added to GWT trunk](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=9513).
Sorting also was added to trunk like a 2 days ago -> [click](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=9493).

Comment: Hi, the link about column resizing in GWT above seems not working